# Clear GRID Serializer Values in hidden field

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, jquery, product-grid, grid-serlization

I have a working Grid Serializer. Now I want to clear the Grid Serializer values without refreshing page. So, I added a jquery script to clear the hidden field:

```
$("input[name='links[products]']").prop("value", "");
```

It works fine when I am on the first page, but when I go to the next page and clear the hidden Grid Serializer it will not clear for the previous page.

I can able to see that the Grid Serializer hidden field was empty, but when I tried to do a search or reset filter the hidden values are posted in the form data.

I don't know how the post values are posted even the hidden field was empty. Is there any way to clear the Grid Serializer values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Serializer\Serializer" name="grid_serializer">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="input_names" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">products</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">base_price[]</item>
                        <item name="2" xsi:type="string">final_price[]</item>
                    </argument>                        
                    <argument name="grid_block" xsi:type="string">customer.product.listing</argument>
                    <argument name="callback" xsi:type="string">getSelected</argument>
                    <argument name="input_element_name" xsi:type="string">links[products]</argument>
                    <argument name="reload_param_name" xsi:type="string">products</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
```

Comment: Finally It worked.